# Matching textbox text to datagridview cell value in .NET

Tags: vb.net

i have 2 textbox to input value and im using barcode scanner.

textbox1 for DIE_NUMBER, textbox2 for STATUS  same as my table column, DIE_NUMBER column have cell value ex:"12345" and STATUS column have cell value "OUT", i want to match this column cell value from 2 textbox then if match DIE_NUMBER value "12345" and STATUS value "OUT"  then add new value to Db only the STATUS value "IN".

Comment: And now you want that we remain stuck for a week too? :) Come on, your expalanation is quite confusing and may cause this question to be closed. Try to elaborate a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
TextBox.Text = DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(3).Value.ToString
```

It allows you to match dgv row to a textbox.